# Validating form with valid image

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a from and trying to validate it with bootstrap form validater. Here validation is working fine , but if a file is validated the valid icon(right mark) has to be come next to the textbox but for me it is coming on next line . Here is the image ,

[image: After validatation]

Here is my markup,

```
<div class="form-group control-group">
<label for="uln" class="control-label col-xs-4">Teacher Id:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-lg-8 controls">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherId" id="teacherId" placeholder="Enter Teacher Id">
        </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I have css as,

```
label.valid {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: url(assets/img/valid.png) center center no-repeat;
display: inline-block;

text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Please help me in this I want the right mark exactly next to the text box.

Comment: Please provde a fiddle. I don't see any label with class "valid".

Comment: I dont know how to make a fiddle . .

Comment: Got to jsfiddle.net and paste your code. Then click "save" and poste the link here. This will help us helping you.

Comment: @DonJuwe Here is my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/rwAP7/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm little bit tricky!!

**CSS Code:**

```
label.valid {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(http://fdata.over-blog.net/99/00/00/05/img/new/portal2-3/body/valid.png) right center no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;    
    right:-5px;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/vx7SW/)**

Comment: Thank u very much , but now it is not showing right mark here . .

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a `span` after the `input`?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwAP7/11/)

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group control-group">
    <label for="uln" class="control-label col-xs-4  ">Teacher Id:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-lg-8 controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherId" id="teacherId" placeholder="Enter Teacher Id">
            <span class="valid"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.valid {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(http://images.videolan.org/images/features/tick.png) center center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set **display: inline-block;** for both input box and the image.

Comment: @user3377978 You need to also add it to the style of the textbox.

Comment: there is no styles for text box

Comment: can you just tell me how to add style for textbox here . .

Comment: <input style="display: inline-block;" type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherId" id="teacherId" placeholder="Enter Teacher Id">

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's the WIDTH property. In bootstrap it's set to 100%, so you have to override this property of the CSS:
`.form-control{ display: inline-block; width:70%;}`